# Local photo management software as good as Google Photos wanted

Tags: file-management, photography, cloud-storage, google-apps, geo-location

I used to organize all my photos on local discs (CDs, DVDs back in the days). I even renamed them using the predecessor of [GeoSetter](http://www.geosetter.de/) and removed all duplicates. 
This was back in the days when I still had time for this.

Then [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) appeared and everything got so much easier. No more manually copying from a camera, just using the smartphone and have them in Google Photos.

Is there any solution that provides the same comfort as Google Photos but locally?

Must:

- Automatic copying from Android smartphone
- Showing the location on a map (Google Maps, if possible)

I like Google Photos for its simplicity but want to keep control over my photos.
[Picasa](http://picasa.google.de/) was not bad but was cancelled and made me switch to Google Photos.

Comment: On which OS shall it run? How much money are you willing to spend in case of paid software? As you're using the `google-apps` tag, must it be an application by Google – or should that indicate it must work with eg. Google Drive?

Comment: Windows is my primary operating system. Linux is running in a Virtual Box. It must not be an application from Google.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/49773/8363

Answer (score 1):

[digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) is open-source desktop software with a lot of features of Google Photos, like galleries, showing photos on a map, and identifying faces.  In my experience, it is both more and less powerful than Google Photos, depending on the feature.