# Map of pictures on my computer, by EXIF geolocation

Tags: maps, image-viewer, geo-location, exif, digital-asset-management

My camera has a GPS sensor, so most of my pictures have a latitude/longitude in their EXIF.

I know I took pictures at a particular location, but I don't remember when and I have so many folders and pictures that searching by looking at a gallery would take ages.

So, I need an app that shows all of my pictures on a map of the world, either as pins or thumbnails.

Requirements:

- Automatically scans all pictures in a particular folder, recursively, and quickly (at least 10 pictures per second).
- Can handle 100.000 pictures (it is OK to show just a fraction of them, then show more when I zoom)
- Works on Linux or Android
- Preferably desktop software rather than a web interface (even if it has to download map tiles)
- Gratis, ideally open source

Comment: There is [Photo Location Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/photo-location-viewer/9wzdncrdg8kl) but it is Windows App only

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos That only shows photos in the Picture Library folder, and only jpg

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/327365/7861 Google My Maps can import from Google Photos, combining multiple photos with the same location into one browsable icon

Answer (score 3):

[digiKam](https://www.digikam.org/) fits most of your requirements.

It is a free and open source image viewer and library manager for Linux.
It has a bunch of managing features around editing tags and EXIF information and also supports GPS location data.

It has a map feature that using Google Maps can overlay your pictures over a map.

To access it, be sure to click the "Map" button at the left of the screen (not the "Map" button at the top of the screen, as that one is not recursive):

[image]

The default map engine does not allow to zoom much. To zoom further than state level, you have to click the small globe button [image] and choose "Google Maps".

When you have found the picture(s) you were looking for, choose the selection tool using this bar: [image]. The [image] button lets you draw a rectangle to select all pictures in that rectangle. The [image] button lets you select an individual picture by clicking on its thumbnail. The details of the selected pictures appear in the right pane.

Comment: Unfortunately this only shows the photo position rather crudely, and doesn't have a detailed satellite map, and is annoying to navigate around

Comment: (Actually the reason it shows it crudely may be because my phone's GPS EXIF tags are crude.) :(

Answer (score 1):

The [Geographic-Map](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki/geographic-map)
of the android gallery app ["A Photo Manager"](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/wiki) (where i am the author of) shows markers where photos where taken/geo-tagged.

I currently use the app with 20 000 photos in 800 different folders on sd-card on my old android-4.2 tablet (and on my new android-7.1 handset), 13 000 photos have exif-geo data

available on [android f-droid.org app store](https://f-droid.org/app/de.k3b.android.androFotoFinder) but not on google play

Comment: "No versions compatible with device" :(

Answer (score 1):

The Google Photos Android app has a map feature.  I'm not sure how you're *supposed* to get to it, but if you type in a place name to the search box and click on the map pin icon, it will open the photo map:

[image: Google Photos overview map]

[image: Google Photos detailed map]

Comment: Does it show all pictures, or only those that match the search? For instance, if I took 100 pictures around the border between two municipalities, will it show only the pictures for the municipality I entered the name of in the search bar?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It shows a placemark icon with a place name in the search box, and then if you select that, it shows photos in that area.  It is not by name, but by location. You can then zoom out and it shows every other location, regardless of what you searched for.