# A simple Windows photo viewer that provides latitude and longitude that can be copied to clipboard

Tags: windows, image-viewer, geo-location

Windows Photos pretends to provide location under Info but it almost never actually does. Some others claim to, for example IrfanView but you have to drill down a bit to find it. There are online EXIF viewers and I may have to settle for that, but I'd actually prefer a Windows application.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/49767/map-of-pictures-on-my-computer-by-exif-geolocation/49773#49773

Answer (score 2):

On Windows (with Cygwin installed or with WSL), you can get the latitude and longitude in your clipboard with this command:

`exif DSCN0025.jpg | egrep 'Latitude|Longitude' | putclip`

Without Cygwin or WSL this would probably work too

`exif DSCN0025.jpg | findstr /I "Latitude Longitude" | clip`

In both cases the `exif` command is the one from this project: https://libexif.github.io

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digikam.org/, might be overkill, but this FOSS app has everything under the sun for photo management (including facial recognition, database and metadata sync) as well as geo-tagging.

More light-weight options (also FOSS) dedicated to handle GeoLocations in photos could be on of these:

> http://www.photoplace.io/

or

> https://github.com/FrancoisSchnell/GPicSync

Comment: Thank you. None of those did the job, however.

Comment: DigiKam specifically, shows the location embedded in EXIF on a map - I'll add a screenshot from my machine. I'd like to help, but I'm unclear of what you are looking for. Could you elaborate what it is specifically that works or doesn't work in other tools?

Comment: IIRC it showed location on their map, but that's not useful. Lat / long in the clipboard is useful. Then I can open the location in a mapping app (e.g. Google maps) for further usage (sharing, determining route to/from, whatever).

Windows Photos is close. Location doesn't work, i.e. they often interpret the location and give a street address or just the state you're in, or nothing at all. I don't want their interpretation. Just the lat / long, which rarely appears. (I also want finer rotation resolution but that's not critical.)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind two shortcuts instead of one, then

[GeoSetter](https://geosetter.de/en/main-en/)

can ease up copying coordinates like this:

1. while photo selected hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> (alternatively right click and select **Edit Data**)
2. select either Decimal or Sexagesimal value and you are free to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

As a bonus (if you are applying image data to another file), you can copy the whole image data content (right click and select **Copy Data to Clipboard**) and paste over another existing file (right click and select **Paste Data from Clipboard**). In next step, you are selecting what will be really replaced.

If you are really after a simple shorthand, I would recommend to stick to any image browser/editor where you can write a simple script ([like this one](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/extract-gps-exif-images-python/)) to output these extracted data to a clipboard ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard)).
I am choosing the Python way, because I like it, however I believe you can follow this approach in any programming language, so its just about the image browser and their scripting support.

For example GIMP can [support Python scripting](https://gimpbook.com/scripting/).

Above mentioned way can be harder to set-up but you have then script shortcut, that will copy GPS coordinates at one click.

Comment: Thank you. I may be able to use these, if I dust off my Python a little. It just blows me away that the simple image viewer/editor I want doesn't exist. Crop, rotate to 0.5° resolution, extract lat / long to clipboard, and some saturation and brightness adjustment. That's it.