# Can someone recommend an image organization software for Linux systems?

Tags: open-source, file-management, images

I have a lot of images (pictures) on my computer and I'd like a solution to tag them somehow, and then return lists of filenames based on some querying criterion.

Ideally this program...

- Runs from command line for easy scripting / interaction with other programs via stdout and stdin (Unix philosophy)
- Is distributed under a FOSS license
- Available from Ubuntu's main repository (or Debian main)
- Keeps the information in a database that I can store on another hard drive
- Can print image filenames to stdout filtered on tags or directory locations

Does anyone know a software for managing images in this way on Ubuntu? I'm not above rolling my own program for this, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Digikam? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/49773/34603

Comment: Actually I discovered something called TMSU which seems almost perfect, except the software isn't a part of Debian or Ubuntu repos, available instead via PPA.